# Serializing custom count field in DRF

Tags: django, django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am trying to send a serialized custom field that has that count of all items in a category in a vessel;
I am trying to understand why this line works:

```
vessel_inventory_category_count = serializers.IntegerField(
        source='vessel_inventory_category.count',
        read_only=True
    )
```

but this doesnt :

```
 vessel_inventory_item_count = serializers.IntegerField(
        source='category_items.count',
        read_only=True
    )
```

serializer.py :

```
class VesselInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    vessel_component_count = serializers.IntegerField(
        source='vessel_components.count',
        read_only=True
    )
    vessel_inventory_category_count = serializers.IntegerField(
        source='vessel_inventory_category.count',
        read_only=True
    )
    vessel_inventory_item_count = serializers.IntegerField(
        source='category_items.count',
        read_only=True
    )

class Meta:
    model = Vessel
    fields = '__all__'
```

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    vessel = models.ForeignKey(
        Vessel, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='vessel_inventory_category')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='category_items')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

vessel model.py:

```
class Vessel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    imo = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='vessel_image')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: please alos add Vessel model here.

Comment: @Meet i just included it

Comment: That's because you are getting vessel info and in category there is a related name field for vessel so you are obtaining count whereas in Item there is no related field for vessel

Comment: @ShishirSubedi is there a way i can do that since Vessel is connected with Category and Item is connected with Category as well ? or must i just add another FK with Vessel.

Comment: @newprogrammer12 you can try SerializerMethodField and make custom resolver. First query category ids from given vessel id and then Count all Items which contains those categories id (using id__in=[category_ids] filter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vessel_inventory_item_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

def get_vessel_inventory_item_count(self, obj):
    # get vessel related category ids
    categories_id = list(obj.vessel_inventory_category.values_list('id', flat=True))
    # return count of those items which are related to vessel category
    return Item.objects.filter(category_id__in=categories_id).count()
```